# Magento If product has attribute, get it's ID

Tags: php, magento, loops, if-statement

I need to get the product ID for product that have an attribute with a certain value.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$found = false;

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
    $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute');
    $id = $_product->getId();

    if ($attribute = NULL) {
        // Do Nothing
    }
    if ($attribute = "value1") {
        echo $attribute . "<br>";
        $value1 = $id;
    }
    if ($attribute = "value2") {
        echo $attribute . "<br>";
        $value2 = $id;
    }
    if ($attribute = "value3") {
        echo $attribute . "<br>";
        $value3 = $id;
    }

    if ($value1 && $value2 && $value3) {
        $found = true;
        echo "All IDs Found" ."<br>";
    }
    if ($found = true) {
        break;
    }
}

echo "Value 1 ID = " . $value1 ."<br>". "Value 2 ID = " . $value2 ."<br>". "Value 3 ID = " . $value3;
```

This mostly work, it loops through the products correctly, and can get the attribute values for each product. But it is showing the ID for the first product in the category, for every product regardless of what attribute they have.

Like this:

```
value1
value2
value3
All IDs Found
Value 1 ID = 17024
Value 2 ID = 17024 (should be 17025)
Value 3 ID = 17024 (should be 17026)
```

How can I get it so that if there is a product in the category with the attribute, and one of the specific values, it will list that products' ID?

Edit:

Using == has fixed part of my issue.

The other problem was that by using:

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute');
```

Was not getting the attribute in a way that allowed me to use it's values. By using this instead:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('attribute');
```

and setting the attribute to 'Use in product Listing'. That allowed me to use if statements, for each value.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to accomplish? It seems like there might be a better way.

Comment: I've figured it out now, I want to have products that have an attribute display at the top of the page above all the others. I just wanted to get the ID of the product as a test to work out if I was getting the correct products, obviously the ID is unique, so I can see straight away if the right product has been selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the value each time:

```
if ($attribute = "value1") {
```

Use double to compare:

```
if ($attribute == "value1") {
```

Comment: That's not giving me any output now, I've also tried using == for $valueX == $id

Comment: plus 1 for quick answer. He simply lose one more `=`

Comment: @Edward144, you made a mistake, but why it doesn't show now, it is another question.

Comment: Yes this does work, I knew it was something else in my code that I'd done wrong. But it's all working now.