# Magento - Get all products in the current category

Tags: php, magento, loops

I am having another issue with what I am trying to achieve here:

[Magento If product has attribute, get it's ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101672/magento-if-product-has-attribute-get-its-id)

Basically what should be happening is, for the current category if there is a product with an attribute with one of three values, then it should be displayed at the top of the page, below the description.

What is happening though is, it is only looping through products on the current page. I think the issue lies with this, in the list.phtml file:

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product);
```

So does anyone know how I can get and loop through all the products in the current category, across all pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

```
$category_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
    ->load();
```

Answer (score 2):

As your answer you need to display product which you are getting in following collection

```
$category_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addCategoryFilter($category)
->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
->load();
```

Then you need to get second time product collection as per requirement to get rest of products :

```
 $_testproductCollection =   Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
   ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin' => $category_id))
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
 $_testproductCollection->load();
```

Comment: That's great for getting the rest of the products, Thanks.